# Alias executed recursively on OSX

Tags: macos, zsh, oh-my-zsh, zshrc, zsh-alias

I'm using oh-my-zsh a have the following alias in .zshrc:

```
alias composer="php -d memory_limit=-1 $(which composer)"
```

I get the following output:

```
$ composer
Could not open input file: composer:
```

And for:

```
$ which composer
composer: aliased to php -d memory_limit=-1 composer: aliased to php -d memory_limit=-1 composer: aliased to php -d memory_limit=-1 /usr/local/bin/composer
$ zsh --version
zsh 5.2 (x86_64-apple-darwin15.4.0)
```

Under Linux it works as expected:

```
$ which composer
composer: aliased to php -d memory_limit=-1 /usr/bin/composer
$ zsh --version
zsh 5.3.1 (x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has nothing to do with it being on OS X or Linux, or the usage of screen. It very much looks like you ran the command

```
alias composer="php -d memory_limit=-1 $(which composer)"
```

multiple times. which lead to the recursive definition of `composer`:

```
composer: aliased to php -d memory_limit=-1 composer: aliased to php -d memory_limit=-1 composer: aliased to php -d memory_limit=-1 /usr/local/bin/composer
```

Adding line-breaks to make it obvious:

```
composer: aliased to php -d memory_limit=-1 \
composer: aliased to php -d memory_limit=-1 \
composer: aliased to php -d memory_limit=-1 \
/usr/local/bin/composer
```

While the first use of `which composer` will return `/usr/local/bin/composer` (or a similar path), subsequent uses will return `composer: aliased to ...`. This leads to the error message that the input file `composer:` (Note the colon) could not be found.

Defining the alias just once will probably work for the most part, but to be safe you can tell `which` explicitly to look for paths (ignoring builtins, aliases and functions) with the parameter `-p`:

```
alias composer="php -d memory_limit=-1 $(which -p composer)"
```

Comment: Nicely done; a note to non-zsh users: in zsh, `which` is a _builtin_ that also reports the definition of _aliases_.

Answer (score -1):

It was an issue with GNU `screen` session. Creating a new `screen` window the alias works as expected.

Comment: This answer isn't useful without explaining how you were using `screen` in the first place, and such an explanation isn't likely to be useful to anyone else. I would just delete the question.